# Передача аргументов call, apply

Tags: javascript

```
  function work(a, b) {
    alert( a + b ); 
  }
  

  function spy(func) {
      return function (...args) {

      return func.apply(null, ...args);// c call рботает
    }
 }
  work = spy(work);
  
  work(1, 2);
```

Второй параметр у apply должен быть массив! ...args ведь является массивом, почему тогда ошибка?
Если использовать call - код работает.

Comment: `...args` это распаковка массива. Через `call` работает, потому что `call` принимает отдельно `N` параметров, а `apply` принимает массив.

Answer (score 1):

`args` - массив, а `...args` - распаковка массива на отдельные составляющие

```js
let test = [1,2,3];

console.log(test);
console.log(...test);
```